# How to set some tensor elements in tensorflow?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I have two tensors.

Logits:

```
tf.Tensor 'MemN2N_1/MatMul_3:0' shape=(?, 18748) dtype=float32
```

The second tensor contains the indices of which I want to set the indexed elements of the first tensor to be zero.

Stories:

```
tf.Tensor 'Reshape_1:0' shape=(?, 2076) dtype=int32
```

For instance, if I have:

```
logits = [[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4,...], [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, ...], ...]

stories = [[0, 2], [1, 3], ...],
```

I then want to modify the `logits` tensor to be:

```
logits = [[0, 0.2, 0, 0.4, ...], [0.1, 0, 0.3, 0, ...], ...]
```

How can I make that happen?